# how to remove the ambiguous function call

Tags: java, function, digital-signature, digital-certificate

Please help me to solve the ambiguous call in this code.

`fac.newtransform()` and `fac.new signedinfo()` is giving error saying:

> reference to `newTransform` is ambiguous, both method `newTransform(String,TransformParameterSpec)` in `XMLSignatureFactory` and method `newTransform(String,XMLStructure)` in `XMLSignatureFactory` match

How can I call the actual function in `XMLSignatureFactory`?

```
   XMLSignatureFactory fac =XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM",
                (Provider) Class.forName(providerName).newInstance());

   Reference ref =fac.newReference("",fac.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA1, null),
    Collections.singletonList(fac.newTransform(Transform.ENVELOPED, null)),null, null);


   SignedInfo si = fac.newSignedInfo
       (fac.newCanonicalizationMethod
         (CanonicalizationMethod.INCLUSIVE_WITH_COMMENTS, 
             null), 
        fac.newSignatureMethod(SignatureMethod.DSA_SHA1, 
            null),
        Collections.singletonList(ref));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must cast the second argument:

```
newTransform("foo", (XMLStructure) null)
```

You are getting the ambiguous warning because `null` is a valid argument to both methods. You need to add the `(XMLStructure)` cast to tell the compiler the type of the object you are setting to `null`..

Answer (score 2):

```
newTransform(Transform.ENVELOPED, null);
```

This call is ambiguous because `null` will match both the method signatures [newTransform(java.lang.String algorithm,
                                       XMLStructure params)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/api/javax/xml/crypto/dsig/XMLSignatureFactory.html#newTransform%28java.lang.String,javax.xml.crypto.dsig.spec.TransformParameterSpec%29) and [newTransform(java.lang.String algorithm,
                                       TransformParameterSpec params)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/api/javax/xml/crypto/dsig/XMLSignatureFactory.html#newTransform%28java.lang.String,javax.xml.crypto.XMLStructure%29). Cast the `null` :

```
newTransform("foo", (XMLStructure) null)
```